# Как поймать ошибку 404 с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, исключения, url, img

Всем доброго времени суток.
Задача следующая: требуется присвоить определенному изображению адрес картинки.
В случае, если картинка будет не найдена по её URL (должно выдать 404 ошибку), то используется другая ссылка.

Вариант который я сделал не подходит, все равно ошибка не обрабатывается.

Есть ли возможность каким-то образом ее поймать?

```html
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        let URL = "https://google.com/invalid/address.png"

        img.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
            console.log("Не удалось загрузить картинку");
        });
        

        img.src = URL;
```

Ошибку в консоли прикрепил в виде картинки

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: попробуй это:  https://learn.javascript.ru/try-catch

Comment: try catch не ловит такие ошибки к сожалению, если тупо в try catch обернуть - не получается

Comment: Зачем вы два раза изображение создаёте?  Попробуйте `img.onerror = myErrorHandlerFunc`

Comment: Ошибка в коде, поправил, а можно по подробнее насчет этого? Что за myErrorHandlerFunc? каким образом это реализовать

Comment: Если есть ошибка, то какая разница с каким статусом будет ответ, меняйте ссылку и все.

Comment: "Что за myErrorHandlerFunc?" обычно в ответах приставка `my` означает, что вам придётся самим написать функцию.

Comment: не дошло сразу, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```js
const imgExists = document.createElement('img');
imgExists.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/PNG_Test.png/477px-PNG_Test.png"

imgExists.onerror = function(a) {
  console.log('imgExists не существует');
};

const imgNotExists = document.createElement('img');
imgNotExists.src = "https://google.com/invalid/address.png"

imgNotExists.onerror = function(a) {
  console.log('imgNotExists не существует');
};
```

Comment: С помощью onerror тоже не получается, не отслеживает

Comment: Что именно у вас не работает? Нажмите выше "Выполнить код" и убедитесь, что в консоли вы увидите только "imgNotExists не существует". Всё отлично работает.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, ошибки 404 невозможно отловить, они проскакивают. Но скрипт они не убивают. В ответе выше от Александр Рогонов, ошибка другого рода, поэтому ее удается отловить